# SSH to Cisco Nexus Switches

Tags: java, cisco

I am using Java ganymed library to connect to our switches with SSH2. I can connect my Catalyst Switches with no problem but when I connect to my Nexus switches I cannot get any outputs from the commands.

Has anybody used this lib to connect Nexus switches?

Here's the specific code part:

```
try {

Connection conn = new Connection(IP);
conn.connect();

boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);

if (isAuthenticated) {

    Session sess = conn.openSession();
    sess.startShell();

    InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

    OutputStream stdin = new BufferedOutputStream(sess.getStdin());

    BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));

    bw.write("sh cdp ne");
    bw.flush();
    stdin.write(13);
    stdin.flush();

    bw.write("exit");
    bw.flush();
    stdin.write(13);
    stdin.flush();

    while (true)
    { 
        String line = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);

        if (line == null) 
            break;
    }
} // close if (isAuthenticated)
} // close try
```

Comment: try using jcsh as a library

Comment: Obvious first question, ssh to the nexus works as expected with an ordinary ssh client program?

Comment: Have you checked if the output maybe goes to `stderr` instead of `stdout`?

Comment: @John Yes I can SSH to the devices using any SSH client.

Comment: @SubOptimal Now I tried reading from stderr and it gives me:
stty: standard input: Invalid argument

Comment: Seems there is no pseudo-terminal allocated and your command `cdp` need one. Check the posts for the message [stty: standard](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22stty%3A+standard%22) if those bring some ideas how to solve you problem. Or try as suggested by @ScaryWombat another library.

Comment: Thanks @SubOptimal I added "sess.requestDumbPTY();" before opening the session and it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem was "there is no pseudo-terminal allocated and your command cdp need one." as @SubOptimal warned.
So I allocated a pseudo-terminal for the session and the problem is solved:

```
Session sess = conn.openSession();
sess.requestDumbPTY(); // Allocate a pseudo-terminal for this session.
sess.startShell();  // Start a shell on the remote machine.
```

Thanks for all the comments.